# Speed up group by

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, groupwise-maximum

Consider the following query:

```
select * 
  from `cg_reviews` 
 inner join `cg_park` on `cg_park`.`cg_id` = `cg_reviews`.`cgr_cg_id` 
 where `status` = 'approved' 
   and `cgr_approval_time` > 0 
 group by `cg_park`.`cg_id` 
 order by `cgr_approval_time` desc limit 3
```

It basically asks for all approved reviews of a park, ordered by approval time and only 1 review per park.  Meaning, I don't want more than 1 review per park, so each of the 3 results must be from a different park (cg_id).

This query works, but even with every index I can think of, is still slow over 18687 rows.  When I remove the group by clause, it is lightning fast.  How else can I do this query with unique parks?

Comment: If you post a question asking for query optimization help, I don't even look at it until you post (a) `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for all your tables, and (b) EXPLAIN for the query. Also would be helpful to qualify all columns in your query so we know which table they belong to.

Comment: You say you want 1 review per park, but which review? The one with the most recent time? Or some other criteria?

Comment: Ordered by approval time, descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment about APPROVED reviews, I have to assume the "status" column is on the reviews table.  It is best to always have table.column or alias.column so others don't have to guess which column belongs where.

That said, I would have a multiple column index to help the order by and grouping. Specifically

```
table        index
cg_reviews   ( status, cgr_cg_id, cgr_approval_time )
```

Your park table cg_id = reviews cgr_cg_id, so since they will be the same value, your group by could be "cgr_cg_id" and take advantage of the index.

Without seeing data, you could have 100 reviews for each "cgr_cg_id" and you only care about the most recent... and from that, you only want the top 3.  This part of the query has no bearing on the PARK table and can be done via

```
select
      r.cgr_cg_id,
      max( r.cgr_approval_time ) latestReview,
   from
      cg_reviews r
   where
          r.status = 'approved'
      and r.cgr_approval_time > 0
   group by
      r.cgr_cg_id
   order by
      max( r.cgr_approval_time ) DESC
   limit 3
```

So now you get 3 records out of all the reviews.  The group by is the park ID column and since ordering by the most recent max time per group, you are not getting the same park with multiple reviews.  Finally you need the details to present to the end-user.  This should be quick as we can now join back to the park and review table on just these three record and should be virtually instantaneous by utilizing same index.  Just make the above query your first from query giving it an alias

```
select
      r2.*,
      p.*
   from
      ( select
            r.cgr_cg_id,
            max( r.cgr_approval_time ) latestReview,
         from
            cg_reviews r
         where
                r.status = 'approved'
            and r.cgr_approval_time > 0
         group by
            r.cgr_cg_id
         order by
            max( r.cgr_approval_time ) DESC
         limit 3 ) PQ

         JOIN cg_reviews r2
            on r2.status = 'approved'
           AND PQ.cgr_cg_id = r2.cgr_cg_id 
           AND PQ.latestReview = r2.cgr_approval_time

         JOIN cg_park p
            on PQ.cgr_cg_id = p.cg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to do the grouping in the larger table before joining rather than after.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM cg_reviews
    WHERE cgr_approval_time > 0
    AND status = 'approved'
    GROUP BY cgr_cg_id
) AS cgr
INNER JOIN cg_park AS cgp ON cgp.cg_id = cgr.cgr_cg_id
ORDER BY cgr_approval_time DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Make sure there's an index on `cgr_cg_id` (if it's declared as a `FOREIGN KEY` the index will be created automatically).

Note that this grouping will not produce reliable results. Since the rows of `cg_reviews` are not uniquely determined by the column you're grouping by, you'll get columns from arbitrary rows in each group. You should probably see [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1) for how to select a well-defined row in each group (e.g. the row with the most recent approval time).

Comment: That didn't speed up anything.  In fact, it is slower.  BTW, status is in cg_reviews.

Comment: I guessed it was in `cg_park` because it doesn't begin with `cgr_`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar.  Unfortunately that query is twice as slow as the original.